# Convert VB Script in Excel to Standalone executable script

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have written a VB script in the Excel module to export charts to a Word document, and it works correctly if I run the module in the Microsoft Visual Basic Application. But I need to write a standalone executable VBScript program so that I can invoke this script programmatically.

I have fixed some errors to make it standalone, but I am getting an expected statement error on line 57.

Below is the VB Script in Excel Module.

```
Sub ExportingToWord_MultipleCharts_Workbook()
    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Object
    Dim WrdDoc As Object
    Dim SecCnt As Integer

    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ChrtObj As ChartObject
    Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ChrCnt As Integer
    
    ' Define paths to Excel and Word files
    excelFilePath = "D:\GIT\modules\core\bin\logs\AssessmentReport.xlsx"
    wordFilePath = "D:\WordDocument.docx"

    ' VBScript to read data from Excel and export tables to Word with formatting

    ' Create Excel and Word objects
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Open Excel workbook
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath)


'Create a new instance of Word
    Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WrdApp.Visible = True
        WrdApp.Activate
        
    'Create a new word document
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
    
    ChrCnt = 0
    
    'Loop through all the worksheets in the Workbook that contains this code.
    For Each WrkSht In objWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        'Fix the instability error
        WrkSht.Activate
    
        'Loop through the charts on the active sheet
        For Each ChrtObj In WrkSht.ChartObjects
        
            'Copy the chart
            ChrtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
            
            'Increment Chart Count
            ChrCnt = ChrCnt + 1
            
            'Fix the instability error
            Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    
            'Paste the Chart in the Word Document
            With WrdApp.Selection
                .PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine
            End With
            
            'Count the pages in the Word Document
            SecCnt = WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
            
            'Add a new page to the document.
            WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add

            'Go to the newly created page.
            WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
            
           
            'Fix instability Errors
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
        Next ChrtObj
    
    Next WrkSht
    
     WrdApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", Filename _
            :="D:\GIT\modules\core\bin\logs\AssessmentReport.xlsx", LinkToFile:=False _
            , DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe" _
            , IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:="AssessmentReport.xlsx"
            
    WrdDoc.SaveAs wordFilePath

End Sub
```

Below is the updated version to run program standalone.

```
Sub ExportingToWord_MultipleCharts_Workbook()
    'Declare Word Variables
    Dim WrdApp, WrdDoc

    Dim strdocname
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim SecCnt

    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ChrtObj
    Dim WrkSht
    Dim Rng 
    Dim ChrCnt
    
    ' Define paths to Excel and Word files
    excelFilePath = "D:\GIT\modules\core\bin\logs\AssessmentReport.xlsx"
    wordFilePath = "D:\WordDocument.docx"

    ' VBScript to read data from Excel and export tables to Word with formatting

    ' Create Excel and Word objects
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Open Excel workbook
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath)


    'Create a new instance of Word
    Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WrdApp.Visible = True
        WrdApp.Activate
        
    'Create a new word document
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
    
    ChrCnt = 0
    
    'Loop through all the worksheets in the Workbook that contains this code.
    For Each WrkSht In objWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        'Fix the instability error
        WrkSht.Activate
    
        'Loop through the charts on the active sheet
        For Each ChrtObj In WrkSht.ChartObjects
        
            'Copy the chart
            ChrtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
            
            'Increment Chart Count
            ChrCnt = ChrCnt + 1
            
            'Fix the instability error
            Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    
            'Paste the Chart in the Word Document
            With WrdApp.Selection
                .PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine
            End With
            
            'Count the pages in the Word Document
            SecCnt = WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
            
            'Add a new page to the document.
            WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add

            'Go to the newly created page.
            WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
            
            'Fix instability Errors
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
        Next ChrtObj
    
    Next WrkSht
    WrdDoc.SaveAs wordFilePath

End Sub
```

Error Message

[image]

Comment: You don't have VBScript in Excel, you have VBA, which is a different language, with a different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use named arguments in VBScript.

So these:

```
With WrdApp.Selection
    .PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine
End With
```

will need to be replaced using commas until the argument is reached in order.

Also the constants will need to either be manually declared or you would need to use their actual values.

```
Const wdInLine = 0
Const wdPasteOLEObject = 0

With WrdApp.Selection
    .PasteSpecial , True, wdInLine, , wdPasteOLEObject
End With
```

... or simply just use their values:

```
With WrdApp.Selection
    .PasteSpecial , True, 0, , 0
End With
```

Comment: Yeah this fixed error for that particular line and similar issue was there for      WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext .

Getting expected end of statement error for below line
        Next ChrtObj

Comment: If you are declaring the constants, they are `Const wdGoToPage = 1`, and `Const wdGoToNext = 2`, which would be: `.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToNext` (or if not, `.GoTo 1, 2`). I personally prefer to declare them for readability, but that all comes down to your preferences.

Comment: If you have Word VBA IDE open, pressing `F2` will bring you to the Object Explorer/Browser. You can paste these constants into the search bar which will show your their defined values.

Comment: Yeah this one is fixed but getting expected end of statement on below line. Is there anything wrong with line

 Next ChrtObj

Comment: Yes in VBScript, you cannot use `Next <Statement>`, it should only just be `Next`. Same thing with `Next WrkSht`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.
This corrected all errors, but it appears that the script is not working; when I run it, nothing happens and no word document is created.

Comment: Ah yes, you probably need to remove the `Sub ... End Sub` or you need to add a line to call it. A line outside of the sub such as `ExportingToWord_MultipleCharts_Workbook` will work. VBS **doesn't require you to use Subs**. Simply placing the code in the body will run it. If you do use them, you **must explicitly call the routine** (or routines if you have more than one).

Comment: No, I have run the script with debug mode on and am getting the below error.


D:\GIT\modules\core\src\main\resources\config>cscript \\D \\s ExportCharts.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation. )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256590/discussion-between-pranavs-and-k-ds).